# If statement not returning expected result

Tags: python

I have run into an issue that totally baffles me.  Everything I feed into this program comes back with a value of -2:

```
def score_mod(score): #This is meant to come up with the adjustment for a given ability score
    if score == 2 or 3:
        mod = -3
    if score == 4 or 5:
        mod = -2
    if score == 6 or 7 or 8:
        mod == -1
    if score == 9 or 10 or 11 or 12:
        mod == 0
    if score == 13 or 14 or 15:
        mod == 1
    if score == 16 or 17:
        mod == 2
    if score == 18:
        mod == 3
    return mod
while True:
    feed = input("Number")
    print(score_mod(feed))
    again = input("Again? Y/N")
    again = again.capitalize()
    if again == "Y":
        continue
    if again == "N":
        break
```

Comment: `score == 2 or 3` is always true, no matter what value `score` has, because if `score == 2` is True, it returns `True`; if `score == 2` is False, `False or 3` evaluates to 3, which interpreted as a boolean is _also_ True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `if score == 2 or 3`.

You can re-write that as `(score == 2) or (3)` which resolves to `False or True` or `True or True`, which is always True.

This is a bit quirky of Python. `bool(any_object)` returns True if the object is not `None`. Try `bool(3)` and see that you get `True` from it.

What you meant to do is `if (score == 2) or (score == 3)` or `if score in [2, 3]`, either of those would work.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: Just want to add to this post, the reason that you got ```-2``` specifically is because in all the other if statements below where you did ```_ or _```, you did ```mod == _``` instead of ```mod = _```. Remember that ```==``` checks for equality, and ```=``` assigns!